# Matrix-Matrix Multiplication Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$  matrices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $AB=I$. Prove that rank$B=n$.

I have reviewed the Systems Rank Theorem. I am thinking I have to prove that B in linearly independent which would result in rank$B=n$ but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: $\textrm{rank }(AB) \le \min ( \textrm{rank }(A),\textrm{rank }(B))$ and $\textrm{rank }(I)=n$.

Comment: @mjw I did not learn that rank$I=n$. I would need to prove it. Is there an alternative proof using linear independence?

Comment: Linear independence of what? Writing things like “$B$ is linearly independent” is imprecise: Do you mean $B$ as an element of a vector space of matrices? Do you mean the columns of $B$? The rows of $B$

Comment: It seems to me that a proof that $I$ has full rank would be almost trivial, and it’s certainly a handy lemma to have in your tool kit.

Comment: Assume the columns of $I$ are dependent.  Then $\sum c_j \mathbf{e}_j =0$ for some $c_j \ne 0$.  Contradiction, the equation $\sum c_j \mathbf{e}_j =0$ has a unique solution $c_1=c_2= \cdots c_n = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=\pmatrix{\mathbf{a_1} \\ \mathbf{a_2} \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{a_n}}$ and $B=\pmatrix{\mathbf{b_1} & \mathbf{b_2} & \cdots \mathbf{b_n}}$.

That is, lets look at the rows of $A$ and columns of $B$.

Since $AB=I$, $a_1 \cdot b_j = 0$ when $1\ne j$ and $a_1 \cdot b_1 = 1$.  So $a_1$ is orthogonal to each row of $B$, other than the first row.  We thus see that $b_1$ cannot be written as a linear combination of the other columns.  Similarly for every column of $B$.  Thus the columns of $B$ are linearly independent.  This is a definition of $\textrm{rank }B =n$, the number of linearly independent columns.